# Using Concave Hull By Case in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, concave-hull

I'm trying to use [Bruce Harold's Concave Hull Estimator Tool](https://community.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/06/11/bruce-harolds-concave-hull-estimator-tool-enhanced) and I'm getting some errors.

When trying to use the tool on ArcMap, I get this:

[image]

There seem to be no object that I can use the tool on, even though what I have loaded is basically points with two attributes:

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  pts.shp
Geometry Type:  Point
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No 

Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
Projection: Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
False_Easting:  0.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   0.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    0.00000000
Auxiliary_Sphere_Type:  0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Is there some other specific change I need to make to use this tool? Is there a better tool for concave hull that's easy to use??

Comment: Could you send me your shapefile ?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message from the results.

Comment: The arrow is that red "X" button. If I click it gives no message, just fails.